# In this akka stream example's running result, why priority job comes after normal job?

Tags: graph, stream, akka

The folling example is from akka stream reference doc.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

/**
  * Created by lc on 2016/1/2.
  */

// A shape represents the input and output ports of a reusable
// processing module
case class PriorityWorkerPoolShape[In, Out](
                                             jobsIn: Inlet[In],
                                             priorityJobsIn: Inlet[In],
                                             resultsOut: Outlet[Out]) extends Shape {
  // It is important to provide the list of all input and output
  // ports with a stable order. Duplicates are not allowed.
  override val inlets: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Inlet[_]] =
    jobsIn :: priorityJobsIn :: Nil
  override val outlets: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Outlet[_]] =
    resultsOut :: Nil

  // A Shape must be able to create a copy of itself. Basically
  // it means a new instance with copies of the ports
  override def deepCopy() = PriorityWorkerPoolShape(
    jobsIn.carbonCopy(),
    priorityJobsIn.carbonCopy(),
    resultsOut.carbonCopy())

  // A Shape must also be able to create itself from existing ports
  override def copyFromPorts(
                              inlets: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Inlet[_]],
                              outlets: scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Outlet[_]]) = {
    assert(inlets.size == this.inlets.size)
    assert(outlets.size == this.outlets.size)
    // This is why order matters when overriding inlets and outlets.
    PriorityWorkerPoolShape[In, Out](inlets(0).as[In], inlets(1).as[In], outlets(0).as[Out])
  }
}

import akka.stream.FanInShape.{Init, Name}

class PriorityWorkerPoolShape2[In, Out](_init: Init[Out] = Name("PriorityWorkerPool"))
  extends FanInShape[Out](_init) {
  protected override def construct(i: Init[Out]) = new PriorityWorkerPoolShape2(i)

  val jobsIn = newInlet[In]("jobsIn")
  val priorityJobsIn = newInlet[In]("priorityJobsIn")
  // Outlet[Out] with name "out" is automatically created
}

object PriorityWorkerPool {
  def apply[In, Out](
                      worker: Flow[In, Out, Any],
                      workerCount: Int): Graph[PriorityWorkerPoolShape[In, Out], Unit] = {
    FlowGraph.create() { implicit b ⇒
      import FlowGraph.Implicits._
      val priorityMerge = b.add(MergePreferred[In](1))
      val balance = b.add(Balance[In](workerCount))
      val resultsMerge = b.add(Merge[Out](workerCount))
      // After merging priority and ordinary jobs, we feed them to the balancer
      priorityMerge ~> balance
      // Wire up each of the outputs of the balancer to a worker flow
      // then merge them back
      for (i <- 0 until workerCount)
        balance.out(i) ~> worker ~> resultsMerge.in(i)
      // We now expose the input ports of the priorityMerge and the output
      // of the resultsMerge as our PriorityWorkerPool ports
      // -- all neatly wrapped in our domain specific Shape
      PriorityWorkerPoolShape(
        jobsIn = priorityMerge.in(0),
        priorityJobsIn = priorityMerge.preferred,
        resultsOut = resultsMerge.out)
    }
  }
}


object ReusableGraph extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("UsingGraph")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val worker1 = Flow[String].map("step 1 " + _)
  val worker2 = Flow[String].map("step 2 " + _)
  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(FlowGraph.create() { implicit b =>
    import FlowGraph.Implicits._
    val priorityPool1 = b.add(PriorityWorkerPool(worker1, 4))
    val priorityPool2 = b.add(PriorityWorkerPool(worker2, 2))
    Source(1 to 10).map("job: " + _) ~> priorityPool1.jobsIn
    Source(1 to 10).map("priority job: " + _) ~> priorityPool1.priorityJobsIn
    priorityPool1.resultsOut ~> priorityPool2.jobsIn
    Source(1 to 10).map("one-step, priority " + _) ~> priorityPool2.priorityJobsIn
    priorityPool2.resultsOut ~> Sink.foreach(println)
    ClosedShape
  }).run()
}
```

build.sbt

```
name := "AkkaStream"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.4.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-testkit_2.11" % "2.4.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-stream-experimental_2.11" % "2.0-M2"
)
```

I run the code, and get the results as follows.

```
step 2 one-step, priority 1
step 2 one-step, priority 3
step 2 one-step, priority 2
step 2 one-step, priority 5
step 2 one-step, priority 4
step 2 one-step, priority 6
step 2 one-step, priority 7
step 2 one-step, priority 8
step 2 one-step, priority 10
step 2 one-step, priority 9
step 2 step 1 job: 2
step 2 step 1 job: 1
step 2 step 1 job: 4
step 2 step 1 job: 6
step 2 step 1 job: 8
step 2 step 1 job: 10
step 2 step 1 priority job: 2
step 2 step 1 priority job: 4
step 2 step 1 priority job: 6
step 2 step 1 priority job: 8
step 2 step 1 priority job: 10
step 2 step 1 job: 3
step 2 step 1 job: 5
step 2 step 1 job: 7
step 2 step 1 job: 9
step 2 step 1 priority job: 1
step 2 step 1 priority job: 3
step 2 step 1 priority job: 5
step 2 step 1 priority job: 7
step 2 step 1 priority job: 9
```

I have two questions:
1. step 2 one-step comes first, yes.
But "step 2 step 1 job" should comes after "step 2 step 1 priority job", why it comes out  before "step 2 step 1 priority job"? 
2. there is only one instance of worker, would the worker part run concurrently or not?

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little old but answering anyway since I stumbled on the same thing.

I think it's just because your computer is fast enough that once it hits this code:

`Source(1 to 10).map("job: " + _) ~> priorityPool1.jobsIn
Source(1 to 10).map("priority job: " + _) ~> priorityPool1.priorityJobsIn`

by the time it sends the second 10 numbers , the first 10 have already been processed. I think that because of this issue they changed the example to 100, but still on my computer I see results similar to yours, but if you slow it down using throttling, you'll see results how you'd expect them:

`Source(1 to 10)
  .throttle(1, 0.1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
  .map("job: " + _) ~> priorityPool1.jobsIn
Source(1 to 10)
  .throttle(1, 0.1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)
  .map("priority job: " + _) ~> priorityPool1.priorityJobsIn`

So, it's not that the results are incorrect, it's just in parallel processing your computer may be too fast.

Of course here throttling is used only to slow down computation and to see our learning example working and should not be used in production unless slowing down computation is actually what you want.